# how to send data from custom authorizer to api endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Say, I have access to a certain value in custom authorizer, how do I pass it on to the api endpoint
what I read till now, is that we could use context in the policy Generator to do that . something like this -

```
 authResponse.context = {
      "key": "this is the data sent from custom authorizer",
      "numKey": 1,
      "mysql":"sdf"
    };
```

but this code is in the policy generator and not in custom authorizer.
so, how do I access the value that I got in custom authorizer and pass it on to the policy generator then??
my main aim is to send that value to the api endpoint.

Comment: you are saying that you want to invoke the lambda function from your custom authorizer?

Comment: no. what I am saying is that I want to send data from custom authorizer to api gateway. basically I have a custom authorizer for my api gateway and i want to send data from my authorizer to my gateway.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that you need to add the information to `authResponse.context`. Once you do that, you can configure it as a URL Query String parameter, or Request Header, etc, via the "Integration Request" interface for your API Gateway method.

[image]

**Now the value which was generated in your authorizer is available to the upstream endpoint of your API Gateway.**

This solution is suggested (but not wholly spelled out) by the following documents:

"[Amazon API Gateway API Request and Response Data Mapping Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters)"

> #### Map Method Request Data to Integration Request Parameters
>
> Integration request parameters, in the form of path variables, query
>   strings or headers, can be mapped from any defined method request
>   parameters and the payload.

["API Gateway Mapping Template Reference"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)

> #### $context.authorizer.property
>
> The stringified value of the specified key-value pair of the context
>   map returned from an API Gateway custom authorizer Lambda function.
>   For example, if the authorizer returns the following context map:
>
> "context" : {   "key": "value",   "numKey": 1,   "boolKey": true }
>   calling $context.authorizer.key returns the "value" string, calling
>   $context.authorizer.numKey returns the "1" string, and calling
>   $context.authorizer.boolKey returns the "true" string.